# Are questions about configuring some feature in some software on-topic (or not)?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I see several questions, related to "*How to configure this software, this feature?*". Should such questions be considered as off-topic (and closed), or not?

I understand we want to concentrate here the knowledge which can help DevOps to do their work, but in some cases SuperUser and Unix&Linux SE sites are more appropriate places to ask "software" questions.

My question is explicitely about the software configuration, run and so on.

Comment: Hey Romeo, please check my attempt to improve your question (mostly to make the title better reflect its content). As always, feel free to further correct or rollback if you don't like my edit. Also, I think this is an extremely interesting question, which IMO is not to be considered as a duplicate (hope my edited title makes that more obvious also). Therefor I suggest for this question to be voted for reopening it. If you agree: do you pull the reopen trigger, or do you want me to do so?

Answer (score 5):

I assume this will depend on the software and the question. Personally, I would let this space grow a bit more before we start closing those questions.

Some tools, I believe, belong here more than in any other sister site (I'm thinking about CI tools and State management tools). It is relevant to have other DevOps' (the people) feedback when configuring such a tool.

That being said, I hope that this site will attract a variety of questions, not just questions about software configuration :)

Answer (score 5):

Absolutely. Software is a core component of devops - if this exchange is to be relevant to devops practitioners, we need to welcome software questions with open arms. Sure, "How do I copy files using robocopy" might be too generic to be ontopic but "How do I ensure that I do not miss any alerts from (well known devops tool X)" might be very relevant to readers.

Comment: IMHO "How do I copy files using robocopy" should be out of topic here. We should not accept questions with answers we can find in documentation....